# Huge battery drain during suspend to ram - 12%/hour - nvidia card doesn't turn off

Tags: nvidia, power-management, suspend, bumblebee, optimus

UPDATE:
So I tracked down the issue. It seems the nvidia card powers up right before suspend. This is expected bbswitch behaviour:

> [ 4195.214014] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics

But for some reason the card is not powered down during the suspend time so as a result it drains battery.

The problem occurs even if I remove the bbswitch module and disable bumblebee.

ideas?

I got a new machine that drains disproportionate amount of battery during sleep: ~12%/hour. It's not a battery problem as the system makes it nearly 5 hours on normal use. Something is definitely wrong. Also the machine gets quite warm while its sleeping (Warmer than when it's running!), leading me to believe that the CPUs fail to suspend or that the nvidia GPU gets turned on prior to sleep?
I can't find anything suspicious on dmesg:

```
[ 4195.095123] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0f1: link is not ready
[ 4195.127994] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from c8:91:f9:14:33:ac by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 4195.134796] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 4195.159421] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[ 4195.164435] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 4195.213683] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[ 4195.214014] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 4195.552620] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 4195.554162] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 4195.555300] PM: Entering mem sleep
[ 4195.555309] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 4195.555541] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 4195.555580] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 4195.556794] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 4195.557634] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[ 4196.586213] PM: suspend of devices complete after 1030.142 msecs
[ 4196.612933] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 4196.612968] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 6117 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:7904 hsw_enable_pc8+0x649/0x7b0 [i915]()
[ 4196.612968] SPLL enabled
[ 4196.612991] Modules linked in: nfsv3 nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfsv4 dns_resolver cpufreq_stats mmc_block ctr ccm joydev mousedev arc4 nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp kvm_intel iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support mxm_wmi kvm iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi btusb uvcvideo crct10dif_pclmul videobuf2_vmalloc crc32_pclmul videobuf2_memops mac80211 videobuf2_core bluetooth v4l2_common videodev crc16 media ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_generic aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd iwlwifi rtsx_pci_ms memstick r8169 cfg80211 snd_soc_rt5640 snd_soc_rl6231 rfkill snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller psmouse snd_hda_codec snd_soc_core mii serio_raw mei_me pcspkr i2c_i801 ie31200_edac snd_compress
[ 4196.613014]  mei shpchp lpc_ich edac_core snd_hwdep thermal battery snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_timer snd wmi i2c_hid soundcore hid regmap_i2c dw_dmac dw_dmac_core i2c_designware_platform gpio_lynxpoint tpm_crb i2c_designware_core evdev 8250_dw spi_pxa2xx_platform snd_soc_sst_acpi tpm mac_hid ac processor sch_fq_codel coretemp msr nfs lockd grace sunrpc fscache ip_tables x_tables sd_mod rtsx_pci_sdmmc atkbd libps2 ahci libahci libata ehci_pci xhci_pci xhci_hcd ehci_hcd scsi_mod rtsx_pci usbcore usb_common i8042 serio sdhci_acpi sdhci led_class mmc_core bbswitch(O) intel_agp i915 button i2c_algo_bit video drm_kms_helper drm i2c_core intel_gtt crc32c_generic crc32c_intel btrfs xor raid6_pq
[ 4196.613016] CPU: 0 PID: 6117 Comm: kworker/u16:5 Tainted: G        W  O    4.0.7-2-ARCH #1
[ 4196.613017] Hardware name: Clevo                         P65_P67SE                       /P65_P67SE                       , BIOS 1.03.09 03/05/2015
[ 4196.613021] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[ 4196.613023]  0000000000000000 0000000020544442 ffff88037f4e3bd8 ffffffff81574ec3
[ 4196.613024]  0000000000000000 ffff88037f4e3c30 ffff88037f4e3c18 ffffffff81074e7a
[ 4196.613025]  000000010011d370 ffff8800c87d0000 ffff8800c87a0360 ffff8800c87a0370
[ 4196.613026] Call Trace:
[ 4196.613030]  [<ffffffff81574ec3>] dump_stack+0x4c/0x6e
[ 4196.613034]  [<ffffffff81074e7a>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
[ 4196.613035]  [<ffffffff81074f05>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
[ 4196.613052]  [<ffffffffa027d039>] hsw_enable_pc8+0x649/0x7b0 [i915]
[ 4196.613059]  [<ffffffffa020df40>] intel_suspend_complete+0xe0/0x6d0 [i915]
[ 4196.613066]  [<ffffffffa020e552>] i915_drm_suspend_late+0x22/0x90 [i915]
[ 4196.613074]  [<ffffffffa020e6d0>] ? i915_pm_poweroff_late+0x40/0x40 [i915]
[ 4196.613081]  [<ffffffffa020e6f7>] i915_pm_suspend_late+0x27/0x40 [i915]
[ 4196.613083]  [<ffffffff813f3a6e>] dpm_run_callback+0x4e/0x160
[ 4196.613085]  [<ffffffff813f4500>] __device_suspend_late+0xd0/0x1c0
[ 4196.613086]  [<ffffffff813f460f>] async_suspend_late+0x1f/0xa0
[ 4196.613088]  [<ffffffff81095ebc>] async_run_entry_fn+0x4c/0x170
[ 4196.613090]  [<ffffffff8108dadb>] process_one_work+0x14b/0x470
[ 4196.613092]  [<ffffffff8108e228>] worker_thread+0x48/0x4b0
[ 4196.613094]  [<ffffffff8108e1e0>] ? init_pwq.part.7+0x10/0x10
[ 4196.613096]  [<ffffffff8108e1e0>] ? init_pwq.part.7+0x10/0x10
[ 4196.613097]  [<ffffffff810934b8>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[ 4196.613099]  [<ffffffff81576a87>] ? schedule+0x37/0x90
[ 4196.613100]  [<ffffffff810933e0>] ? kthread_worker_fn+0x170/0x170
[ 4196.613102]  [<ffffffff8157a718>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
[ 4196.613103]  [<ffffffff810933e0>] ? kthread_worker_fn+0x170/0x170
[ 4196.613105] ---[ end trace 0462ac18f83abc29 ]---
[ 4196.632978] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 46.732 msecs
[ 4196.634053] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 4196.634105] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 4196.634195] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[ 4196.646328] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 13.339 msecs
[ 4196.646594] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 4196.647677] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 4196.647682] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 4196.647712] intel_pstate CPU 1 exiting
[ 4196.648884] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU1
[ 4196.648894] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 4196.649158] intel_pstate CPU 2 exiting
[ 4196.650323] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU2
[ 4196.650351] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 4196.650647] intel_pstate CPU 3 exiting
[ 4196.651789] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU3
[ 4196.651794] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 4196.652058] intel_pstate CPU 4 exiting
[ 4196.653187] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU4
[ 4196.653198] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[ 4196.653483] intel_pstate CPU 5 exiting
[ 4196.654589] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU5
[ 4196.654594] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[ 4196.654890] intel_pstate CPU 6 exiting
[ 4196.655992] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU6
[ 4196.655996] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[ 4196.656297] intel_pstate CPU 7 exiting
[ 4196.657403] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU7
[ 4196.657410] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[ 4196.658869] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 4196.658908] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 4196.659265] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 4196.659303] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 4196.659304] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 4196.671284] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU1
[ 4196.673556] CPU1 is up
[ 4196.673574] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[ 4196.685547] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU2
[ 4196.687842] CPU2 is up
[ 4196.687859] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 4196.699759] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU3
[ 4196.701974] CPU3 is up
[ 4196.701990] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
[ 4196.713823] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU4
[ 4196.716068] CPU4 is up
[ 4196.716080] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
[ 4196.727888] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU5
[ 4196.730054] CPU5 is up
[ 4196.730066] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
[ 4196.741889] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU6
[ 4196.744146] CPU6 is up
[ 4196.744158] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
[ 4196.755988] kvm: enabling virtualization on CPU7
[ 4196.758252] CPU7 is up
[ 4196.763641] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 4196.764541] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[ 4196.767964] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 4196.767976] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 4196.767980] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 4196.778689] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 14.131 msecs
[ 4197.018061] PM: early resume of devices complete after 239.206 msecs
[ 4197.018354] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 4197.018587] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 4197.018588] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[ 4197.344855] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 4197.351524] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4197.352268] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4197.385019] usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 4197.558906] usb 1-4: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
[ 4197.793332] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 4198.253693] usb 1-10: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 4198.475535] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 4198.485939] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 4198.600697] PM: resume of devices complete after 1581.666 msecs
[ 4198.601227] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[ 4198.601228] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 4198.608986] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[ 4198.608999] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150204/nsarguments-95)
[ 4198.615505] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[ 4198.615510] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[ 4198.634618] psmouse serio2: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5706], y [..4800]
[ 4198.905731] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[ 4199.141472] r8169 0000:03:00.1 enp3s0f1: link down
[ 4199.142315] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 4199.142524] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Any ideas? Running on Arch Linux, Intel i7 4720 HQ and GTX 970M

Comment: The clue is at the the top, I think, about i915. You have a discrete/intel GPU hybrid? Sorry, you already mention it in the question. Yes, that's probably it.

Comment: Could you elaborate? It is the integrated GPU that has some sort of crash, I don't see any signs of the discrete there?

Comment: That's because they don't both run at the same time. The way they're supposed to work is one powers on while the other powers off. Your integrated GPU is probably called up by the kms drm drivers only to find the nvidia *(which uses its own special kms thingy)* is already at full-throttle - only to throw your exception. I'm pretty sure there are ways [around it](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173439).

Comment: I just checked. The nvidia is powered down at suspend. (via the proc interface) it can't be interfering. Also the intel is always powered on because it's the only one connected to the display output (X). Nvidia draws on it via virtualGL.

Comment: Well, in that linked comment thread the op eventually says that the nvidia was being powered up when the intel powered down at suspend. It's just a quick one I found at the time. Anyway, I could be wrong about why, but your error definitely points to your GPU